# The colour of a JQuery Mobile button doesn't change colour

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have created a small JQuery mobile application that contains three tab buttons, one button used to access a different page. By using the pre-configured data-theme="a", a button pressed turns to blue color when it is pressed and the related page is loaded. This works for the first time the button is clicked, but when the button is clicked for a second time in order to access again the same page (from another page), the button doesn't turn blue again, but it remains dark grey. Does anyone know where the solution of this issue may be? 
The code of one of the pages, as a demo, is given below. Thanks in advance

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="chart">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" class="headerBar" data-theme="a">
       <a href="#busstat" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" class="back-button">Back</a>
        <div align="center" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
            Cars
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-fullscreen="true" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
        <div id="container" class="container"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true" class="footerBar">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#chartYear" data-role="tab" class="ui-btn-active footer-button" data-transition="slideup" >Last Year</a></li>
                <li><a href="#chartMonth" data-role="tab" class="footer-button" data-transition="slideup">Last Month</a></li>
                <li><a href="#charWeek" data-role="tab" class="footer-button" data-transition="slideup">Last 7 Days</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: just give me some minutes..

Comment: Since this is a CSS issue, the CSS would definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the class 'ui-state-persist' to the selected tab does the job:

```
<li><a href="#chartYear" data-role="tab" class="ui-btn-active footer-button ui-state-persist" data-transition="slideup" >Last Year</a></li>
```